# Closing drywall to duct work

Tags: drywall, garage, ducts

We are trying to convert some garage space into a gym, and one the we’re concerned about is all the gap space between the drywall and the ducting. We want to seal that off as much as possible for air quality. How could we close off these gaps or loose fits?

A couple of examples: 
[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you perceive the air quality being impacted by the gaps ?

Comment: I guess that’s a good question— we don’t see anything that’s obvious/directly connected to bad air quality. It’s a pretty nasty old garage, though, and I assumed it wouldn’t be great to be sucking it all in on a regular basis. The ceiling is full of old insulation and there’s evidence of past moisture damage, and we’re concerned about that circulating around, so we wanted to seal and paint to lock it all in. This morning we noticed hornets going in through one gap, so there’s bound to be a nest in there somewhere.